# Python: Understanding global a little bit more

Tags: python

I have a program in python. part of the program is:

```
suggestengines = get_suggestengines(suggestengines) 
sleeptimer = sleepcount * len(suggestengines)
seeds = get_seeds(dummydata=False)
```

For further programming I want to make a function of it:

```
def first_step():
    suggestengines = get_suggestengines(suggestengines)
    sleeptimer = sleepcount * len(suggestengines)
    seeds = get_seeds(dummydata=False)
```

Now I get an error for "suggestengines" that I want to pass into get_suggestengines(). Also sleep timer and seeds get a marker, that I don't use them in the rest of the program. I googled it and got the answer: Us global. So I added global for everything

```
def first_step():
    global suggestengines
    global sleeptimer
    global seeds
    suggestengines = get_suggestengines(suggestengines) #which engines to run?
    sleeptimer = sleepcount * len(suggestengines) 
    seeds = get_seeds(dummydata=False)
```

In further part of the program I have

```
for seed in tqdm(seeds, leave=True):
```

there the program gives me an error vor seeds in tqdm. If I change it to also make a def of it like:

```
def partTwo():
    for seed in tqdm(seeds, leave=True):
```

Then I don't get an error anymore although I didn't used global. Can someone explain me why and if I need to use global in part 2 also?

Comment: Please post more info regarding errors.

Comment: I didnt tried to start the program. Just PyCharm underlines the single words red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
global <identifier>
```

tells python that `<identifier>` should refer to a global when used in assignments. This is necessary in functions that change globals because Python has no syntactical difference between declaring a variable and assigning to an existing variable. The default in python is to have assignments in functions create new variables, rather than change global state.

When you just read from a variable there is no syntactic ambiguity, so Python will just use whatever variable it finds (i.e. global if there is no local one).

Example:

```
a = 1

def foo():
    a = 2 # this will create a new, local variable a

def bar():
    global a # "when I refer to a, I mean the global one"
    a = 2    # this will change the global variable a
```

If no global with the specified name exists, the `global` statement itself will not create a new global variable, but any following assignment will. E.g. given the following:

```
def x():
    global c

def y():
    global c
    c = 1

def z()
    print c
```

`x(); z()` would be an error(global name 'c' is not defined), while `y(); z()` would print `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`seeds` hasn't been initialized yet by the time the for loop is hit, since its initialization is part of a `def` that hasn't been called yet. If you put the for loop inside a `def` then it will be called in the order you call the functions, so the interpreter won't complain until you actually use it.

**The only thing to keep in mind here is this: use variables after they have been initialized.**

Comment: and if I call first_step() and after partTwo()

Will partTwo work with the seeds I initialized in first_step without calling global seeds in partTwo()?